# how to fix when i zoom in to model parts disappear

Tags: mesh, objects, shaders, edit-mode, object-mode

there is an issue with my blender file. when i zoom into the model parts disappear from view so its really hard to add detail and fix topology. how do i fix? it is probably a small issue however i would like yo get it resolved. this here is an image of the problem. it kin of reminds me of when you have an imported fbx file as i believe i did that when i exported an reimported my own model however it was working just fine. it just suddenly happened when i opened it
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the ***" Clip Start "*** distance in your view properties. Decrease it to 0.001 or lower, and this problem will be fixed:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU WORKS A TREAT!!!

Comment: @JustImpact No problem, have fun !)

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Please avoid answering a question twice when it is obviously a duplicate. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform Yeah, it was a duplicate, but sometimes what's the problem when you can answer it and later mark it as a duplicate ;)

Comment: Not really a big problem for me. But in my opinion, there should still be no duplicates if possible, and in addition, the person who has already answered the question should get the reputation. Don't you think? ;-)

Comment: @quellenform I agree; though the question was already linked by the time I answered, so the best of both sides. Normally I just mark it as a duplicate and go on ;)